# Save Image to MySQL After crop Using ajax And PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, angularjs

Below code crops the image after chosen from the local then provides a copy.

Is there a possible way to save the cropped image to MySQL as I have seen many articles but they use PHP for both server side and client side but as am using this to a mobile app where that allows JavaScript or Jquery in client side.
And on server side am using PHP.

[JSfiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/alexk111/rw6q9/#&togetherjs=l8thHKmKri)

HTML:

```
 <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
      <div>Select an image file: <input type="file" id="fileInput" /></div>
      <div class="cropArea">
        <img-crop image="myImage" result-image="myCroppedImage"></img-crop>
      </div>
      <div>Cropped Image:</div>
      <div><img ng-src="{{myCroppedImage}}" /></div>
    </body>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngImgCrop'])
  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myImage='';
    $scope.myCroppedImage='';

    var handleFileSelect=function(evt) {
      var file=evt.currentTarget.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (evt) {
        $scope.$apply(function($scope){
          $scope.myImage=evt.target.result;
        });
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    };
    angular.element(document.querySelector('#fileInput')).on('change',handleFileSelect);
  });
```

Comment: There is no such thing as using php client side, browsers don't run php

Comment: @charlietfl this am not using this as a web app this is go in to b converted to a mobile application using phonegap. FYI: phone gap do not support php( that supports only HTML,CSS,JAVASCRITPS) ON CLIENT SIDE.

Comment: Hi Shaik, How did you solve this problem?

Comment: do you have any idea about this?

Comment: @vanarajcs sorry for late reply if you have not yet figured it out the first thing you have to do is let the user crop the image later the second image where the cropped is projected keep that in a hidden field pass that `src` to Mysql save is as a bloob and let me know if works

Comment: Hi Shaik, Thanks for your reply. I have achieved it in another way.

Comment: I have used this.

    `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $data['img']);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $file = "images/4.jpg";
    file_put_contents($file, $data);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

 $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $data['img']);

 $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);

 $data = base64_decode($img);

 $file = "images/4.jpg";

 file_put_contents($file, $data);
```